# Rselenium with PhantomJS does not open a page

Tags: r, web-scraping, phantomjs, rselenium

I'm trying access a web service (https://spot.cgsmd.isi.edu/submit.php) using RSelenium with PhantomJS. I don't encounter any issue when using Chrome but with PhantomJS, I cannot navigate to this web page.

I thought it could be because of "https://" so with help from this forum I added the below options. Still not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Best,

-E

```
remDrv <- rsDriver(browser = "phantomjs", port = 4444L,
                   extraCapabilities = list("--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1", "--web-security=no"))

remDrv$client$navigate("https://spot.cgsmd.isi.edu/submit.php")
#### remDrv$client$navigate("https://duckduckgo.com") ## DOES WORK

remDrv$client$getCurrentUrl()
```

> remDrv$client$getCurrentUrl()
>
> [[1]]
>
> [1] "about:blank"

Comment: Your code works for me under windows and port `4567` not passing the extra capabilities.

Comment: yet I still cannot get it to open. might be a mac issue?